# Unable to use HTML attributes on custom components in TSX

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jsx

For starters, I'm using `jsx: "preserve"` with this `jsx.d.ts` file, taken from a quick Google search on the subject.

```
import Vue, {VNode} from "vue";

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface Element extends VNode {}
    interface ElementClass extends Vue {}
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      [elem: string]: any;
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, while everything I found pretty much provided this exact declaration file, none of the results went further in-depth about how to use JSX with custom components.

In my case, I have a component defined with `Vue.extend()` that I'd like to use within JSX. This component is the default export in a file called `SomeComponent.tsx`. The code that's causing the issue looks like this.

```
import Vue, {CreateElement} from "vue";

import SomeComponent from "./SomeComponent.tsx";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "SomeOtherComponent",
  functional: true,
  render: (h: CreateElement) => (
    <div class="something">
      <SomeComponent
        class="something-else"
        someProp={1234}
      >
        Slot Content
      </SomeComponent>
    </div>
  )
});
```

Compilation fails at line 11, column 9 with the following message: `TS2339: Property 'class' does not exist on type 'ComponentOptions<Record<string, any> & Vue, DefaultData<Record<string, any> & Vue>, DefaultMethod...'`.

I understand that it fails to type-check the use of `class="something-else"` on the custom component.
Taken from the [JSX in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3203) proposal on GitHub:

> `<Something x={expr1} { ...spr } y={expr2} />`
>   Given an element attributes type `E` derived from `Something` in the above example, the attributes of the element are checked as follows:
>
> If the attribute is a normal attribute `P` initialized with `expr`:
>   If `E` has a property `P`, process `expr` with the contextual type of the type of `E.P`. Otherwise, issue an error.
>   It is an error if `expr` is not assignable to `E.P`.

However, what I don't know/understand is how I'd be able to get the `class` attribute to type-check properly, i.e. in what way I'd need to adjust my `jsx.d.ts`.

If need be, I would also be fine with disabling type-checking for JSX, but I'm unsure how I would do that as well. Here's what I tried so far.

According to the proposal linked above

> If the element type is `any`, the element instance type is `any`.

I tried setting `JSX.ElementClass` to `any` by replacing `interface ElementClass extends Vue {}` with `type ElementClass = any`, but it failed with the same error at the exact same location.

I also tried adding `interface ElementAttributesPropert {}` to my `jsx.d.ts`, in accordance with

> The interface `JSX.ElementAttributesProperty` defines this process. It may have 0 properties, in which case all attributes are assumed to be valid and of type `any`, [...].

This, in turn, produces another error, that is

```
TS2322: Type '{ class: string; someProp: number; }' is not assignable to type 'CombinedVueInstance<Record<string, any> & Vue, object, object, object, Record<never, any>>'.
  Type '{ class: string; someProp: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Vue'.
    Property '$el' is missing in type '{ class: string; someProp: number; }'.
```

I know this code *should* work, as I've run it through Babel after manually removing the TypeScript parts and receiving the expected output.

### Edit for Matt McCutchen:

This is the definition for `SomeComponent` I have. It's pretty much just a wrapper around `<router-link />` rigged to do something additional on click. Works like a charm in regular templates, e.g. SFC `<template>`. The only reason I've tried to solve this with JSX was [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6872) issue with templates and functional components.

```
import Vue, {CreateElement, RenderContext} from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "SomeComponent",
  functional: true,
  render(h: CreateElement, {children, data}: RenderContext) {
    const doStuff = () => console.log("Hello there!");

    return (
      <router-link
        {...data}
        nativeOnClick={doStuff}
      >
        {children}
      </router-link>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm no expert on custom JSX configurations in TypeScript, but I'll fiddle with your project if you provide enough code to reproduce the problem.  It looks like I need the definition of `SomeComponent`.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Edited the question with the info you requested

Answer (score 2):

I was able to shut off type checking of JSX attributes by adding the following to `namespace JSX` in `jsx.d.ts`:

```
type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = {[name: string]: any};
```

(For reasons I have not investigated, `type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = any;` does not work.)

Getting proper type checking would be a matter of defining `JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes` to calculate the JSX attributes type of a component from the component type.  But [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13260#issuecomment-270276955) suggests the calculation is very complex for Vue (in contrast to React).

Comment: Sadly, this did not fix my issue (the error messages didn't even change), but I still thank you for your effort to try and help with this fairly outlandish issue.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript 3.0 or newer for `JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes` support?  I'll make the usual offer that if you publish a repository that reproduces the problem, I'll mess with it.

Comment: I wasn't using TypeScript 3 yet, that explains it. I guess I'll upgrade and get back to you in case it doesn't work.